# Permutation Testing

Tags: r

I have the following data set for which I've written some code to do permutation testing

```
df <- read.table(text="Group   var1    var2    var3    var4    var5
1           3   5   7   3   7
1           3   7   5   9   6
1           5   2   6   7   6
1           9   5   7   0   8
1           2   4   5   7   8
1           2   3   1   6   4 
2           4   2   7   6   5
2           0   8   3   7   5
2           1   2   3   5   9
2           1   5   3   8   0
2           2   6   9   0   7
2           3   6   7   8   8
2           10  6   3   8   0", header = TRUE)
```

This is my code. However it doesn't seem to work for some reason - all the p values I get at the end are about 0.5. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong??

```
data = df[,2:6]
t.test.pvals = matrix(NA,nrow=1000,ncol=5)
ids.group1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
ids.group2 = c(7,8,9,10,11,12,13)

#Define binary vector type for the t test
group1.binary <- rep(0,times=6)
group2.binary <- rep(1,times=7)
type <- c(group1.binary,group2.binary)

#Permutation testing
for (i in 1:1000) {
index = sample(1:13, size=13, replace=F)
group1 = data[which(index %in% ids.group1),]
group2 = data[which(index %in% ids.group2),]
group.total = rbind(group1,group2)
temp = t(sapply(group.total, function(x)
unlist(t.test(x~type)[c("p.value")])))
temp = as.vector(temp)
t.test.pvals[i,] = temp
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either do a t-test or do permutation testing. In the permutation testing, you don't use t-tests. See for instance [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/kenrice/sisg/SISG-08-06.pdf) for a tutorial on permutation testing. Below you find the code for your particular example (e.g. var5):

```
# t-test
with(df, t.test(var5~Group))$p.value
# Permutation testing
# mean difference
mean.diff <- with(df, abs(mean(var5[Group==1])-mean(var5[Group==2])))
# function that calculates resampled mean
one.test <- function(x,y) {
  xstar<-sample(x)
  abs(mean(y[xstar==1])-mean(y[xstar==2]))
}
# calculating the resampled means 
many.diff <- c(mean.diff, with(df, replicate(1000, one.test(Group, var5))))
# pvalue
p5 <- mean(abs(many.diff) >= abs(mean.diff))
p5
```

The way you did it, you resampled and then calculated p-values from a t-test. After the resampling, the p-value is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1. Therefore when you look at `summary(t.test.pvals)`, you see uniformly distributed p-values (as expected).

Answer (score 1):

`@shadow` explained the issue with your code well. If I were you I would generally refrain from coding this kind of thing from scratch. The `coin` package implements all the permutation tests you could ever want to use. No need to re-invent the wheel.

This code

```
library(coin) 
sapply(df[,-1], function(x) pvalue(oneway_test(x ~ as.factor(df$Group))))
##  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5 
## 0.548 0.544 0.898 0.685 0.304
```

does what you seem to want to do (i.e., test whether there is a shift in the distribution of `varX` in `Group` 1 versus `Group` 2).